# Users don't see some contacts after deleting aggregated rawcontact because name_raw_contact_id don't change

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

I have a problem with NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID in the **Contacts table**.
The problem is users don't see some contacts after deleting aggregated rawcontact.

I hope there are any ways to![enter image description here][1] solve the problem.

In **/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db**, Contacts table has  NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID field, which has rawcontactid of the contact.

The problem occurs when aggregating contacts.

When deleting the rawcontact of the aggregated contacts, occasionally the value of NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID is not valid. Because NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID hasn't been changed.

Because of this problem, Contacts table holds data, but it doensn't appear in the contacts app.

I don't see this problem on **Samsung** device, because NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID is changed automatically.
However, it's not changed automatically, on **LG and other** devices.

To summarize, these are my questions.

1. Is there any way I can change the value of NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID in Contacts table?
2. Is there any way to delete raw contact in RawContacts table without problem?